# Removing the bar in standard UITableView programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove the topbar from a UITableView in code? So in this case, remove the "Books" bar?

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking that bar isn't on the UITableView; it's on the UINavigationController that manages the UIViewController that manages the table view.

The answer below, if put in the UIViewController, works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```