# Adding Arrow Picture in Android ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

Is there any way to add an image to the right of Android's ListView. It needs to look similar to a type UITableView as shown in [Removing the bar in standard UITableView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150799/removing-the-bar-in-standard-uitableview-programmatically)

Comment: From the Android Design Guide:
*Don't use right-pointing carets on line items
A common pattern on other platforms is the display of right-pointing carets on line items that allow the user to drill deeper into additional content.

Android does not use such indicators on drill-down line items. Avoid them to stay consistent with the platform and in order to not have the user guess as to what the meaning of those carets may be.*

Comment: You can find what @error-454 cites here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html Look for "Don't use right-pointing carets on line items".

Comment: @Error454 tell that to my clients...  I have this argument all the time.  I say "well that might be what it looks like in iOS, but it's not really the Android way to do it" and they say "But that's what we want" so I charge them a lot of money to make it look the same as iOS...  That doesn't mean this isn't a valid question and it doesn't mean "Just don't do it that way" IS a valid answer. To put it another way:  My Client's Design Guide > Android Design Guide.

Comment: @akousmata Back in Jun of 2012, lots of android developers were copying iOS UI, so I felt the comment was relevant. I agree with you obviously, unfortunately customers don't always want what's sensible, established and easy to maintain. If you're asked to maintain an app that has right-pointing carets on the line items, run fast and run far.... for it is full of dirty dirty hacks.... You can also see this was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I was commenting more in frustration than anything else as I'm knee deep in a project where the client wanted this after being told 3 times that it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an image to the right of the text on a row by putting the ListView, TextView and ImageView in a RelativeLayout and setting `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for the TextView and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the ImageView. I have blogged about this [here](http://willvk.blogspot.com/2011/07/adding-arrow-image-to-right-of-listview.html).